# Perl: If two elements match print elements, else iterate until match and then print

Tags: perl, for-loop, foreach

I'm new to Perl and I'm trying to iterate over two elements of an array with multiple indices in each element and look for a match. If element2 matches element1, I want to print both and move to the next position in element1 and continue the loop looking for the next match. If I don't have a match, loop until I get a match. Here is what I have:

```
@array = split(',',$row);

foreach $element1(@array[1])
{
  foreach $element2(@array[2])
  {
    if($element1 == $element2)
    {
       print "1 = $element1  :  2 = $element2 \n";
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not getting the the matched output. I've tried multiple iterations with different syntactical changes.
I can get both elements when I do this:

```
foreach $element1(@array[1])
{
  foreach $element2(@array[2])
  {
       print "1 = $element1  :  2 = $element2 \n";
  }
}
```

I thought I might not be dereferencing correctly. Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is data of `$row`? And what about [last](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) .?

Comment: wouldn't `@array` be single dimensional array? and its elements will be of string type, where you need to use `eq` for comparison... ex: `if($str1 eq $str2)`

Comment: $row is a line of the @file.

Comment: Hi @user652256, it would help a great deal if you could share some sample input and expected output. There are a number of issues with your script and it's difficult to determine exactly what you're trying to do, despite your explanation.

Comment: what do you mean by "**move to the next position in element1**". Looks like a element1 is an array element and how it has multiple elements?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your script. Briefly:

- You should always use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).
- Array indices start at 0, not 1.
- You get an element of an array with `$array[0]`, not `@array[0]`. This is a common frustration for new Perl programmers. The thing to remember is that the sigil (the symbol preceding a variable name) indicates the type of value being passed (e.g. `$scalar`, `@array`, or `%hash`) to the left-hand side of the expression, not the type of datastructure being accessed on the right-hand side.
- As @sp-asic pointed out in the comments on the OP, string comparisons are performed with `eq`, not `==`.
- References to datastructures are stored in scalars, and you dereference by prepending the sigil of the original datastructure. If `$foo` is a reference to an array, `@$foo` gets you the original array.
- You apparently want to break out of your inner loops when you find a match, but you'll want to make it clear (for people who look at this code in the future, which may include yourself) which loop you're breaking out of.

Most critically, `@array` will be an array of strings after you split another string (the row) on commas, so it's not clear why you expect to be able to treat the strings in the first and second position as arrays that you can loop through. I have a few guesses about what you're actually trying to do, and what your inputs and expected outputs actually look like, but I'll wait for you to provide some additional information and leave the information above as general guidance in the meantime, along with a lightly-reworked version of your code below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = split(',', $row);

foreach my $element1 (@$array[0]) {
    foreach my $element2 (@$array[1]) {
        if ($element1 eq $element2) {
            print "1 = $element1  :  2 = $element2\n";
            last;
        }
    }
}
```